# Efficiently Adding Multiple Columns to DataFrame Using withColumn and UDF in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame with three columns: Data, Col1, and Col2. I want to use the withColumn function in scala to create 300 additional columns based on the following logic :

```
val outDataFrame = inputDataFrame;
var i = 0;
while (i < myObjList.size) {
    val x = myObjList.get(i)
    val stInd = x.getStartSplitIndex + 1
    val length = x.getEndSplitIndex - x.getStartSplitIndex
    val convertDataType = x.getDataType()
    val outColName = x.getName()

    // The following line is not working
    outDataFrame = outDataFrame.withColumn(outColName,col(myFunc(convertDataType,substring(col("Data"),stInd,length).toString())))

    i += 1
}
```

In this code snippet, `myObjList` is a list of objects with a length of 300, each representing the specifications for creating a new column. The `myFunc` function performs data conversion, taking two arguments: `convertDataType` (a string) and `dataToConvert` (a string).

The `stInd` and `length` values are derived from the current object `x`, providing information about which slice of the Data column I should use to generate the corresponding new column.

I'm seeking guidance on an optimized approach for achieving this task. The input DataFrame contains ***billions*** of records, so ***performance optimization is crucial***.

Thank you.

Comment: You're writing this is a way that is not very functional. It is more readable to `.map` over your `myObjList` (then you don't have to create your counter) but this won't matter that much for performance. If you care about performance you've skipped the most crucial part of all: please share your `myFunc` function. What you're showing here is not performance critical, since with this you're just creating your query plan (adding a bunch of columns to your df in a loop). But not what the calculations are.

Comment: please add some sample input & output ? also what is the inside logic of udf?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use withColumn, use select instead with a Seq[Column] you build up in a single projection.  Spark does not always optimise out the projections which can end up in a severe performance penalty.

Wrt. myFunc use the in-built Spark functions wherever possible, UDFs are significantly slower.  **IF** you must squeeze out every drop of performance when doing custom conversion logic then use Expressions directly and implement code gen, but be warned the interfaces are Spark internal and can change each release.

It can be as simple as (taken from [Quality](https://github.com/sparkutils/quality)):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.{CodegenContext, ExprCode}
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.{BinaryExpression, Expression}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{DataType, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

object AsUUID {
  def apply(lower: Column, higher: Column): Column =
    new Column(AsUUID(lower.expr, higher.expr))
}

/**
 * Converts a lower and higher pair of longs into a uuid string
 * @param left
 * @param right
 */
case class AsUUID(left: Expression, right: Expression) extends BinaryExpression {
  protected def withNewChildrenInternal(newLeft: Expression, newRight: Expression): Expression = copy(left = newLeft, right = newRight)

  override protected def doGenCode(ctx: CodegenContext, ev: ExprCode): ExprCode =
    defineCodeGen(ctx, ev, (lower, higher) => s"org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String.fromString(new java.util.UUID($higher, $lower).toString())")

  override def dataType: DataType = StringType

  override protected def nullSafeEval(lower: Any, higher: Any): Any =
    UTF8String.fromString(new java.util.UUID(higher.asInstanceOf[Long], lower.asInstanceOf[Long]).toString)
}
```

allowing you to use:

```scala
df.select(AsUUID(col("lower"), col("higher")))
```

but this code will be executed in-line with other Spark code gen and without the performance penalty of converting to Scala types and back again to Catalyst via Encoders.  Only go this route if it brings significant savings, e.g. if for a billion rows taking 1hr with UDFs and 40m with Expressions that 20m saving may be worth it for you (example numbers, but UDFs are typically up to 2x slower).  The learning curve and hurdles of working with internal apis probably aren't worth a small gain in perf unless you will use those Expressions in other places.

Comment: [evidence for withColumn woes](https://lansalo.wordpress.com/2018/05/13/spark-how-to-add-multiple-columns-in-dataframes-and-how-not-to/)

Answer (score 0):

`.withColumn` returns a *new* dataframe, that you basically discard, and keep adding columns to original one (and discarding).

You should make some effort to write more idiomatic code, it will help avoid problems like this and many others in the future.

```
val newDF = myObjList.foldLeft(oldDF) { case (df, x) => 
 val start = x.getStartSplitIndex + 1
 val length = x.getEndSplitIndex - start + 1
 df.withColumn(
   x.getName, 
   col(
     myFunc(x.getDataType, substring(col("Data"), start, length))
   )
 )
}
```

Comment: That missed by mistake while drafting question (edited that) but the issue is expression in withColumn is not working.

Comment: "not working", can you be more specific please?  Is there a compilation error, runtime error etc.?, I thought the question was about performance

Comment: @DeepGhodasara `.witColumn` is working. Something in the way you wrote it might not, but it is impossible to discern from your description. Your updated piece of code will not even compile .... I don't think it makes too much sense to try and salvage that at this point.
Just take the snippet I suggested, and see if it does what you want. If not, come back and describe _exactly_ what happens vs. what you expect.